# Finding digits in powers of 2 fast

Tags: python, algorithm, math, language-agnostic

The task is to search every power of two below 2^10000, returning the index of the first power in which a string is contained. For example if the given string to search for is "7" the program will output 15, as 2^15 is the first power to contain 7 in it.

I have approached this with a brute force attempt which times out on ~70% of test cases.

```
for i in range(1,9999):
    if search in str(2**i):
        print i
        break
```

How would one approach this with a time limit of 5 seconds?

Comment: Are there constraints on the search string you take in input?

Comment: @Save yea there is, forgot to mention. The search string will be less than 200 characters

Answer (score 5):

Try not to compute `2^i` at each step.

```
pow = 1
for i in xrange(1,9999):
    if search in str(pow):
        print i
        break
    pow *= 2
```

You can compute it as you go along. This should save a lot of computation time.

Using `xrange` will prevent a list from being built, but that will probably not make much of a difference here.

`in` is probably implemented as a quadratic string search algorithm. It may (or may not, you'd have to test) be more efficient to use something like [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) for string searching.

Comment: Also, `xrange` instead of `range`

Comment: What kind of increase would I see in using KMP for string searching?

Comment: @user1411838 - it's hard to say. While KMP is linear in the size of the two strings, the quadratic algorithms implemented in programming languages are usually optimized quite heavily, so the difference might not be big. You would have to test to make sure.

Comment: @IVlad I'll give it a go and see what happens, any other suggestions for making this faster? Maybe not calculation every power? im not really sure

Comment: @user1411838 - I'm not sure. What increase do you get just by avoiding `**` and using `xrange`? Can you multithread it?

Comment: @IVlad Unfortunately theres no multithreading, the increase was very slight, only a couple of milliseconds.

Comment: There might be some pattern or mathematical fact in the powers that you need to take advantage of. I'll give it more thought, I don't see what else you can do so far. If this problem is from an online judge site, can you please link to it?

Comment: In Python, `a in b` uses a Boyer-Moore-Horspool-like algorithm when `b` is a string. See [`stringlib/fastsearch.h`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8e180b2067e4/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h).

Answer (score 4):

A faster approach could be computing the numbers directly in decimal

```
def double(x):
    carry = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(x):
        d = v*2 + carry
        if d > 99999999:
            x[i] = d - 100000000
            carry = 1
        else:
            x[i] = d
            carry = 0
    if carry:
        x.append(carry)
```

Then the search function can become

```
def p2find(s):
    x = [1]
    for y in xrange(10000):
        if s in str(x[-1])+"".join(("00000000"+str(y))[-8:]
                                   for y in x[::-1][1:]):
            return y
        double(x)
    return None
```

Note also that the digits of all powers of two up to 2^10000 are just 15 millions, and searching the static data is much faster. If the program must not be restarted each time then

```
def p2find(s, digits = []):
    if len(digits) == 0:
        # This precomputation happens only ONCE
        p = 1
        for k in xrange(10000):
            digits.append(str(p))
            p *= 2
    for i, v in enumerate(digits):
        if s in v: return i
    return None
```

With this approach the first check will take some time, next ones will be very very fast.

Comment: A suffix tree is faster than searching this huge string because the lookup is independent of the size of this huge string — it only depends on the search string.

Answer (score 2):

Compute every power of two and build a suffix tree using each string.  This is linear time in the size of all the strings.  Now, the lookups are basically linear time in the length of each lookup string.

I don't think you can beat this for computational complexity.

Comment: This sounds interesting, how would one go about writing a basic suffix tree in python? Would the calculating of the powers be the same?

Comment: @user1411838, yeah, it's all the same code; just using the appropriate data structure so that repeated searches are faster.

Answer (score 2):

There are only 10000 numbers. You don't need any complex algorithms. Simply calculated them in advance and do search. This should take merely 1 or 2 seconds.

```
powers_of_2 = [str(1<<i) for i in range(10000)]

def search(s):
    for i in range(len(powers_of_2)):
        if s in powers_of_2[i]:
            return i
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
twos = []
twoslen = []
two = 1
for i in xrange(10000):
    twos.append(two)
    twoslen.append(len(str(two)))
    two *= 2

tens = []
ten = 1
for i in xrange(len(str(two))):
    tens.append(ten)
    ten *= 10

s = raw_input()
l = len(s)
n = int(s)

for i in xrange(len(twos)):
    for j in xrange(twoslen[i]):
        k = twos[i] / tens[j]
        if k < n: continue
        if (k - n) % tens[l] == 0:
            print i
            exit()
```

The idea is to precompute every power of 2, 10 and and also to precompute the number of digits for every power of 2. In this way the problem is reduces to finding the minimum i for which there exist a j such that after removing the last j digits from 2 ** i you obtain a number which ends with n or expressed as a formula (2 ** i / 10 ** j - n) % 10 ** len(str(n)) == 0.

Comment: What would happen to this if it encountered an input not in a number? something like 31415926535897932

Answer (score 0):

A big problem here is that converting a binary integer to decimal notation takes time quadratic in the number of bits (at least in the straightforward way Python does it).  It's actually faster to fake your own decimal arithmetic, as @6502 did in his answer.

But it's **very** much faster to let Python's `decimal` module do it - at least under Python 3.3.2 (I don't know how much C acceleration is built in to Python `decimal` versions before that).  Here's code:

```
class S:
    def __init__(self):
        import decimal
        decimal.getcontext().prec = 4000  # way more than enough for 2**10000
        p2 = decimal.Decimal(1)
        full = []
        for i in range(10000):
            s = "%s<%s>" % (p2, i)
            ##assert s == "%s<%s>" % (str(2**i), i)
            full.append(s)
            p2 *= 2
        self.full = "".join(full)

    def find(self, s):
        import re
        pat = s + "[^<>]*<(\d+)>"
        m = re.search(pat, self.full)
        if m:
            return int(m.group(1))
        else:
            print(s, "not found!")
```

and sample usage:

```
>>> s = S()
>>> s.find("1")
0
>>> s.find("2")
1
>>> s.find("3")
5
>>> s.find("65")
16
>>> s.find("7")
15
>>> s.find("00000")
1491
>>> s.find("666")
157
>>> s.find("666666")
2269
>>> s.find("66666666")
66666666 not found!
```

`s.full` is a string with a bit over 15 million characters.  It looks like this:

```
>>> print(s.full[:20], "...", s.full[-20:])
1<0>2<1>4<2>8<3>16<4 ... 52396298354688<9999>
```

So the string contains each power of 2, with the exponent following a power enclosed in angle brackets.  The `find()` method constructs a regular expression to search for the desired substring, then look ahead to find the power.

Playing around with this, I'm convinced that just about **any** way of searching is "fast enough".  It's getting the decimal representations of the large powers that sucks up the vast bulk of the time.  And the `decimal` module solves that one.